Given $n > 1$, let $p$ be a prime number such that $n < p < 2n$ (by the way, there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$).
Given $n > 1$, let $p$ be a prime number such that $n < p < 2n$ (by the way, there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$). Does $p$ divide $\binom{2n}{n}$? Explain.
What I did
I found out that this is an example of Lucas' Theorem, which states that:
Let $m,n$ be two natural numbers, $p$ be a prime. Suppose that  $m, n$ admit the following base $p$ representation
$$m=m_0+m_1p+\cdots+m_sp^s,\qquad n=n_0+n_1p+\cdots+n_sp^s$$
with $0\le m_i, n_i \le p-1$, then
$$\binom{n}{m}\equiv\prod_{i=0}^{s}\binom{n_i}{m_i}\ (\bmod p)$$
I am wondering on how to apply Lucas' Thereom to this problem, if it is even the correct application.

You can apply Lucas Theomrem directly. What have you done in that regard?  IE What is $ 2n$ in base $p$? (Hint it's 2 digits) What is $n$ in base $p$? (Hint it's 1 digit) Hence, what is $ {2n \choose n } \pmod{p}$?  $\quad$. The key here is that the units digit of $2n$ is smaller than the units digit of $n$, hence it is $ 0 \pmod {p}$.

Rearrange $\binom{2n}{n}=\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ to be instead $\binom{2n}{n} n!n! = (2n)!$
Since $p$ will divide the RHS (it is one of the terms in the expansion of $(2n)!$ as a product) it must also divide the LHS but it can not divide either of the $n!$ terms and so must divide $\binom{2n}{n}$ by Euclid's lemma.
